# Limiting user access to my website - OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I have my php app hosted on OpenShift. I would want to test it with a limited set of users. So is there a native way to limit access to my website using their IP address or I will have to settle with .htaccess.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, we don't have a built-in-tool that will restrict who can view your app. I would suggest using a login page and/or the .htaccess method you mentioned.

If your looking to add collaborators to your application then I would suggest checking out: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/chap-Members.html